# can not build unity suddenly

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for
>   details. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -
>          Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/fluentp/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools"
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[
>       Error: Unable to read 'D:\Project\FacebookLogin\Facebook\debug.keystore'
>       Error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
>       ]
>       stdout[
>
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
>   psi,     UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>       UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[]
>   sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>       UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

this is the error message on the unity console; 
it worked well ... but suddenly made out errors on the console... when i tried to build... 
please help me...

Comment: Please format your error message next time.

Comment: @Amylinn sorry;;;i  did not know about it;;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

> Error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

You entered wrong password for `keystore` in Publishing Settings. Or you are not using the keystore that you used earlier to sign your APK.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer.but... i entered password. it worked again. i did not delete the stored information. (playerpref) so i used playerpref.deleteall(). and then it worked again;;;;;do not know why;;;

Answer (score 1):

Check your keystore name is debug.keystore. If its correct,please check the alias and password.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i cheked it ;;; i used playerpref.deleteall (). and then it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue creates when switching between the platform, try to update the Project Keystore and Project Key password [image]